# Functionality on Jupyter notebooks not working

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed Jupyter using pip3 on my macbook. The instructions told me to download anaconda but I am trying to be consistent by using visual studio code.
also

So I found a way to install it on visual studio code but there were features missing like the tab button will not work.

I ran start notebook and when I bring up jupyter notebooks and in the first cell type import pandas as pd. Juypter acts like it has never heard of pandas before. So I ask myself, well I probably should have installed anaconda. I tried installing it before, realized that I had visual studio code and uninstalled it previously. I tried installing anaconda and it says installation failed contact anaconda. They want me to pay for some anaconda cloud service. I am unemployed right now and am trying to cut on costs.

I have tried checking the visual studio code documenation and it says download anaconda which I cannot do. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks

I have tried looking at stack overflow articles.

I have contacted anaconda support but they have not gotten back to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was advised to download anaconda and than run the anaconda software. By doing so, anaconda was able to load the way it wanted to and was able to utilize all imports and features. This included jupyter.